# Why does lazy evaluation seem to work differently for a Num than an Int in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In GHCI if I do..

```
let x = 1 + 2
```

then

```
:sprint x
```

I get

```
x = _
```

then if I do

```
x

3
```

then..

```
:sprint x
```

I still get

```
x = _
```

However if I do

```
let x = 1 + 2 :: Int
```

Then the second :sprint x gives me

```
3
```

Just wondering why that is?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the type of `1 + 2`: it's `Num a => a`. That means it can be any numeric type, specified by whoever uses `x`. So if you evaluate it once, GHCI's defaulting rules mean it defaults to `Int`, and then you evaluate `x :: Int`, which is indeed `3 :: Int`. However, that can't be saved as the value for `x`, because someone might later try to use it as `x :: Double`, for example, and the answer would be different.